# Vagrant box add fail

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I was trying to add

> laravel/homestead

box in vagrant but i get different errors.

By running

> vagrant box add laravel/homestead

I get this error

```
The box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found or could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via `vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/homestead"] Error:
```

I tried to 'vagrant login' and i logged in successfully but still receiving same error.

I tried to download the box manually, However, I still having problems adding it.

by running this command

> vagrant box add laravel/homestead [Path in Windows]

i get

```
==> box: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v0) for provider:
    box: Unpacking necessary files from: file://C:/Users/eNull/Downloads/hc-download
    box:
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.
```

My OS: Windows 10.

cUrl version: curl 7.45.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) libcurl/7.45.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2d zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 libssh2/1.6.0 librtmp/2.3

vagrant: 1.8.1

VirtualBox: 5.0.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

I downloaded

```
cUrl x64 with SSL
```

and replace it with the curl.exe provided by Vagrant.

In other words, I copied the curl.exe to

```
C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\bin
```

Now it's working perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You don`t need to add the box from web. Init instead of this:

```
vagrant init laravel/homestead
vagrant up
vagrant ssh
```

Vagrant should add homestead in boxes list automatically. 
If you want to set up local downloaded box, you will be get better to add box directly from box directory.:

```
cd [path in windows]
vagrant box add [name_box] laravel/homestead
vagrant up
vagrant ssh
```

Comment: It says The box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:


But actually i'm logged in!

Comment: What about local installation of downloaded box?

Comment: I've posted the solution in my case already.

by changing the curl. It's not working. Locally and over internet.

But wondering why in local started to work since in local they don't use cUrl :/

Comment: And I'm wondering what`s the point of curl? How did it help you?

Comment: Well, vagrant box add will hit the ATLAS Servers to get "laravel/homestead" in this case they use the cUrl. So when i updated that it worked. But locally i'm not sure why it actually worked. maybe they have some requests to ATLAS for different reasons. If i get an answer i will post it here.

Answer (score 0):

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead
```

Comment: The question already has a marked answer, you're just dumping one line of code here without any surrounding explanation.

Answer (score 0):

use chocolate down cUrl，and  replace it with the curl.exe provided by Vagrant. then it works.

I find error by script: vagrant box add {box path} --debug