# Vagrant box add fails with local file

Tags: windows, vagrant, virtualbox

I just followed this tutorial: https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/building-a-vagrant-box and finally faced this issue:

```
h:\VagrantBoxes>vagrant box add test-server32 file:///H:/VagrantBoxes/package.box
==> box: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> box: Adding box 'test-server32' (v0) for provider:
    box: Unpacking necessary files from: file:///H:/VagrantBoxes/package.box
    box:
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.
```

I use Windows 10 x64, Vagrant 1.8.1, VirtualBox 5.0.12.

Similar problem was listed here: [Vagrant box add fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556929/vagrant-box-add-fail), but the solution does not work for me.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `file://` instead of `file:///` ?

Comment: @hek2mgl, if I pass `file://` link to browser it resolves it to `file:///`. Nevertheless, both variants do not work.

Comment: What if you just try: `H:/VagrantBoxes/package.box` ?

Comment: @hek2mgl Unfortunately, it's all the same. Also tried simply `package.box` when being inside `VagrantBoxes` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. 
I tried to run curl from `<vagrant_dir>/embedded/bin` and found out, that `vcruntime140.dll` is missed on my PC. So I installed fresh "Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015" and the issue disappeared.