# vagrant box add not recognizing local metadata json file

Tags: json, windows, vagrant

I am trying to provide my own vagrant basebox in combination with a metadata json file to handle the versioning. However if I try to add the box using to vagrant it fails. Vagrant does not seem to recognize the file as metadata and instead tries to add it as a box, which does not work.

*vagrant box add*

```
PS C:\Vagrant\Boxes> vagrant box add C:\Vagrant\Bento\builds\metadata.json
==> box: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
A name is required when adding a box file directly. Please pass
the --name parameter to vagrant box add. See
vagrant box add -h for more help.
```

*metadata.json*

```
{
    "name": "devops",
    "description": "Bla",
    "versions": [{
        "version": "0.1.0",
        "providers": [{
            "name": "virtualbox",
            "url": "file://C:/Vagrant/Bento/builds/debian-9.3.virtualbox.box"
        }]
    }]
}
```

*vagrant box add --debug*

```
 INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence...
 INFO runner: 1 hooks defined.
 INFO runner: Running action:  #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x000000000482b258>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::BoxAdd:0x00000000046d7640>
 INFO environment: Running hook: authenticate_box_url
 INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence...
 INFO runner: 2 hooks defined.
 INFO runner: Running action: authenticate_box_url #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x000000000464dbe8>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::LoginCommand::AddAuthentication:0x0000000005444fd0>
DEBUG client: No authentication token in environment or C:/Users/a.b/.vagrant.d/data/vagrant_login_token
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<VagrantPlugins::LoginCommand::AddAuthentication:0x0000000005444fd0>
 INFO box_add: Downloading box: file:///C:/Vagrant/Bento/builds/metadata.json => C:/Users/a.b/.vagrant.d/tmp/boxed9966a6bed3c379b7650df171216dd6eb5788c8
 INFO interface: output: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
 INFO interface: output: ==> box: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> box: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
ERROR warden: Error occurred: A name is required when adding a box file directly. Please pass
the `--name` parameter to `vagrant box add`. See
`vagrant box add -h` for more help.
 INFO warden: Beginning recovery process...
 INFO warden: Recovery complete.
 INFO environment: Running hook: environment_unload
 INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence...
 INFO runner: 1 hooks defined.
 INFO runner: Running action: environment_unload #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x00000000056cc0f0>
ERROR vagrant: Vagrant experienced an error! Details:
ERROR vagrant: #<Vagrant::Errors::BoxAddNameRequired: A name is required when adding a box file directly. Please pass
the `--name` parameter to `vagrant box add`. See
`vagrant box add -h` for more help.>
ERROR vagrant: A name is required when adding a box file directly. Please pass
the `--name` parameter to `vagrant box add`. See
`vagrant box add -h` for more help.
ERROR vagrant: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_add.rb:136:in `add_direct'
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_add.rb:120:in `call'
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/plugins/commands/box/command/add.rb:78:in `execute'
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/plugins/commands/box/command/root.rb:66:in `execute'
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:42:in `execute'
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:308:in `cli'
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/bin/vagrant:138:in `<main>'
 INFO interface: error: A name is required when adding a box file directly. Please pass
the `--name` parameter to `vagrant box add`. See
`vagrant box add -h` for more help.
A name is required when adding a box file directly. Please pass
the `--name` parameter to `vagrant box add`. See
`vagrant box add -h` for more help.
 INFO interface: Machine: error-exit ["Vagrant::Errors::BoxAddNameRequired", "A name is required when adding a box file directly. Please pass\nthe `--name` parameter to `vagrant box add`. See\n`vagrant box add -h` for more help."]
```

Adding the box directly works

```
PS C:\Vagrant\HoBo> vagrant box add C:\Vagrant\Bento\builds\debian-
9.3.virtualbox.box --name devops
==> box: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> box: Adding box 'devops' (v0) for provider:
box: Unpacking necessary files from: file:///C:/Vagrant/Bento/builds/debian-
9.3.virtualbox.box
box:
==> box: Successfully added box 'devops' (v0) for 'virtualbox'!
```

I already checked for the Visual Studio C++ Redistributable 2015 to be installed both in x64 and x86 versions ([Vagrant box add fails with local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34578834/vagrant-box-add-fails-with-local-file)) and already tried to replace the curl file ([Vagrant box add fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556929/vagrant-box-add-fail))

System: Windows 10 Pro x64
Vagrant Version: 2.0.1

Any help would be appreciated as I do not know why vagrant does not recognize the json file correctly :-/

Comment: I had the same problem, it was a syntax error in the JSON! Beware of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of research if finally found the error.

The problem was the encoding of the metadata.json file. I exported the file using UTF8-BOM which prevented vagrant from recognizing it correctly. After converting to UTF8 or ASCII the box could be added using the metadata file.

Comment: I don't have a metadata file, just using `vagrant box add ubuntu_aws aws_ec2_dummy.box`

I still get the error though...